# FacebookSDK.a increasing installed app size dramatically on iOS with Unity

Tags: ios, facebook, size

I have tried this with an empty project. Integrating the FacebookSDK.a lib which is linked by the official Unity Facebook plugin makes the size of the **installed app** (appname.app) jump from 8~9MB to 70MB.

Note that I am not talking about ipa size which stays normal, but really the installed app size.

I don't think this is normal and I am wondering if there is a way not to link the FacebookSDK.a and do it with the normal FBSDKCoreKit.framework instead ? or actually any other way that doesn't have such a huge impact on installed app size.

Comment: I have the same issue. On Android the app size barely changed, on IOS the FacebookSDK.a weights 50MB. My .apk is 13MB on Android; .app is 105MB on iOS... Hopefully someone from Facebook can tell us why and if we can avoid that.

Comment: BTW, i noticed the .a file contains x86, arm, arm, x64, unknown. Maybe we can remove all but arm and x64 from it ? I'm a Unity & windows developer, I don't know anything about xcode, ios or a files... Do you have any leads ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to test this further but this might be an option yes. Not sure how you can do this though. I don't know if you can strip things from a .a file.

Comment: In fact, i managed to do it (using lipo and ar commands, check this http://jennismfma.blogspot.fr/2012/11/ar-is-fat-file-use-libtool1-or-lipo1.html) , and now the .a file is 12MB. However, this has no impact at all on the installed app size. I'm guessing, once the app is compiled, everything that concerns other architectures is stripped away anyway. So i'm stuck with a large app for now.

Comment: Did you clean the project before rebuilding ? Sometimes if you don't it won't take notice of the changes.

Comment: Yeah, i did clean and rebuild.

Comment: To add a final note, my app is 105MB installed, the package i uploaded was around 250MB, and displayed app size on the store is 36MB. That last info is kind of reassuring.

Comment: So in the end it worked ? You should post an answer and I'll validate it if it did work.

Comment: Nope, i abandoned trying to improve on what i had in the last comment, so i wouldn't consider it solved. But anyways, it wasn't the biggest issue i had when trying to integrate Facebook in my app. Let's just say that i'll never do it again :)